# setting the value of select by partially specifying the first parameter value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I have 2 `select2` controls, both has same data loaded into them

I know that `$("#basic").val("44||four||another||data4").trigger("change")` will set as "invalid"

I need to set "invalid" just by setting the value as 44. 
Likewise when I specify 22 it must specify the selected as "bug"

Note that it should entirely match the first parameter of id string separated by ||, ie when `$("#basic").val("44").trigger("change")` should not select 444.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
      <select id="advanced">
      </select>
      <select id="basic">
      </select>
      <script>
         var data = [
             {
                 id: "11||first||another||data1",
                 text: 'enhancement'
             },
             {
                 id: "22||second||another||data2",
                 text: 'bug'
             },
             {
                 id: "33||third||another||data3",
                 text: 'duplicate'
             },
             {
                 id: "444||fourfour||another||data44",
                 text: 'Junk'
             },
             {
                 id: "44||four||another||data4",
                 text: 'invalid'
             },
             {
                 id: "55||five||another||data5",
                 text: 'wontfix'
             }
         ];
         
         $("#advanced").select2({
           data: data
         })
         
         
         $("#basic").select2({
           data: data
         })
         

         $("#basic").val("44").trigger("change")
         
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a selectValue function that wraps your change. That way you'd be able to select an option based on any value of the key.

```
selectValue = function (value) {
  let id = data.find(item => {
    let ids = item.id.split("||")
    if(ids && ids.indexOf(value) !== -1)
      return true
  })
  // you need this check in case no id was found
  if(id) {
    id = id.id
    $("#basic").val(id).trigger("change")
  }
}
//usage
selectValue("44")
```

If data isn't a global variable make sure to add it as a function argument

```
selectValue = function (data, value) {
  let id = data.find(item => {
    let ids = item.id.split("||")
    if(ids && ids.indexOf(value) !== -1)
      return true
  })
  // you need this check in case no id was found
  if(id) {
    $("#basic").val(id.id).trigger("change")
  }
}
//usage
selectValue(data, "44")
```

Also this assumes that `another` part of your key was just a placeholder. All parts of your id would need to be unique from each other for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`attributeStartsWith`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```js
var data = [{"id":"11||first||another||data1","text":"enhancement"},{"id":"22||second||another||data2","text":"bug"},{"id":"33||third||another||data3","text":"duplicate"},{"id":"444||fourfour||another||data44","text":"Junk"},{"id":"44||four||another||data4","text":"invalid"},{"id":"55||five||another||data5","text":"wontfix"}];

$("#advanced").select2({
  data: data
})

$("#basic").select2({
  data: data
})

$("#basic option[value^=44]").prop('selected', true).trigger("change")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="advanced"></select>
<select id="basic"></select>
```